# Video reported to have a framerate of 15fps, but when played seems like 30. How to tell?

Tags: ffmpeg, framerate, ffprobe

I have a video that I'm processing and transcoding to another format via ffmpeg. I've come across this before where the reported fps in ffprobe seems to be half of what it is when played but don't understand why. Problem is that when ffmpeg processes this file, the output is using the seemingly misreported framerate and I have to override it and redo the file.

Here's the stream info for the video stream:

```bash
$ ffprobe -i file.mp4 -print_format json -show_streams 2>/dev/null
```

```json
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "Main",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0000",
            "width": 1920,
            "height": 1080,
            "coded_width": 1920,
            "coded_height": 1080,
            "closed_captions": 0,
            "has_b_frames": 1,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 40,
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "field_order": "progressive",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "true",
            "nal_length_size": "4",
            "r_frame_rate": "15/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "15/1",
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start_pts": 67,
            "start_time": "0.067000",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            }
        },
```

How can I tell this is the case and not actually 15fps? Looking for a programmatic way to detect this case.

---

```
$ ffprobe -version
ffprobe version 4.4.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
```

Windows build

Comment: At the moment, I am blanket assuming anything reported to having 15 or 14.985 fps  is actually double but I'd like to find a more reliable way to detect this.

Comment: Execute `FFprobe` with `show_packets ` argument: `ffprobe -select_streams v -show_packets file.mp4`. Look at `pts_time` and `duration_time`. For 15 fps the minimum delta between two pts should be `0.0667` seconds, and the duration should be `0.0667` seconds. You may look for frames counting, and divide the number of frames by video duration.

Comment: Hmm, yeah so sample it myself. I think I can do that as a verification if I see 15 or 14.985.

Comment: Some fields are missing from the ffprobe output. Which version?

Comment: @Gyan, v4.4.1 one of your builds. :) Though out of date it seems.

Comment: The missing fields (duration, bit_rate..) are shown in 4.4.1 as well.